# Pass PHP Variable to External Form via URL

Tags: php, javascript, variables, global-variables

I wonder whether someone could help me please.

I'm capturing a `Session variable` within a HTML form as follows:

```
$lid = $_SESSION['lid'];
```

From this main HTML form, using the following lines of code, I then load an external ajax table using the 'mysqlajaxtableeditor` software:

```
</script> 
 <!-- Set ajax url -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            trackHistory = false;
            var ajaxUrl = 'Example3.php';
        </script>

<body id="page2" onload="toAjaxTableEditor('update_html','');">
```

What I'd like to be able to do, is capture the `Session variable` from the main form and pass it to the external ajax table.

I've read a number of posts on this site which I hoped I would be able to solve my problem from, but I just can't seem to pass the value across.

From what I've read, I've tried the following on my main form :
`var ajaxUrl = 'Example3.php?lid=$lid';`, then in the receiving AJAX table script, `$lid = $_GET['lid'];` but it doesn't work and i'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

For additional information, I've posted the AJAX table code below:

```
class Example1 extends Common
{
    function initiateEditor()
   {
      $tableColumns['findid'] = array('display_text' => 'Find ID', 'perms' => 'TV');
      $tableColumns['dateoftrip'] = array('display_text' => 'Date of Trip', 'perms' => 'ETV');
      $tableColumns['finddescription'] = array('display_text' => 'Find Description', 'perms' => 'ETV');
      $tableColumns['detectorname'] = array('display_text' => 'Detector Used', 'perms' => 'EVT');
      $tableColumns['searchheadname'] = array('display_text' => 'Search Head Used', 'perms' => 'ETV');
      $tableColumns['pasref'] = array('display_text' => 'PAS Ref.', 'perms' => 'ETV');

      $tableName = 'finds';
      $primaryCol = 'findid';
      $errorFun = array(&$this,'logError');
      $permissions = 'EID';

      require_once('php/AjaxTableEditor.php');
      $this->Editor = new AjaxTableEditor($tableName,$primaryCol,$errorFun,$permissions,$tableColumns);
      $this->Editor->setConfig('tableInfo','cellpadding="1" width="800" class="mateTable"');
      $this->Editor->setConfig('tableTitle','');
      $this->Editor->setConfig('orderByColumn','dateoftrip');
      $this->Editor->setConfig('editRowTitle','Edit Details');
      $this->Editor->setConfig('iconTitle','Edit Find Details');
   }


   function Example1()
   {
      if(isset($_POST['json']))
      {
         session_start();
         $this->mysqlConnect();
         if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
         {
            $_POST['json'] = stripslashes($_POST['json']);
         }
         if(function_exists('json_decode'))
         {
            $data = json_decode($_POST['json']);
         }
         else
         {
            require_once('php/JSON.php');
            $js = new Services_JSON();
            $data = $js->decode($_POST['json']);
         }
         if(empty($data->info) && strlen(trim($data->info)) == 0)
         {
            $data->info = '';
         }
         $this->initiateEditor();
         $this->Editor->main($data->action,$data->info);
         if(function_exists('json_encode'))
         {
            echo json_encode($this->Editor->retArr);
         }
         else
         {
            echo $js->encode($this->Editor->retArr);
         }

      }
   }
}
$lte = new Example1();
?>
```

I just wondered whether someone could possibly look at this please and let me knwo where I'm going wrong?

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: i've not understend, but could you use an ajax style subitting: like $.post... var1, var2, var3 to Example3.php

Comment: Adding it to the filename is the right approach. But we can't know if your AJAX or table file loading method (neither shown) strip the parameters out again (if default GET parameters get added).

Comment: Hi @mario, thnak you for this, and my apologies for omitting the table code. I've now added this to my original post. Kind regards

Comment: Hi @AlexBall, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. I'm afraid I'm fairly new to AJAX, and I'm not quite sure what you mean. Could you perhaps elaborate on this. If it helps, I've now added the AJAX Table code to my original post. Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM hi, for example i use a ajax structure like this: `function myfunc(){$.ajax({type: 'POST',url: '/url/phppage.php',dataType: 'json',data: {id: $("#items_id").val(), items1: $("#items1").val(),...},success: function(data){//alert(data.message);} }); }`to post data from ajax to php page...

Comment: Hi @AlexBall, I see, thank you fro clearing that up. Kind regards

Comment: did you use single quotes here: `var ajaxUrl = 'Example3.php?lid=$lid';`?

Comment: Hi @Arvin, thank you for taking the time to help me. Yes I did try using single quotes, but unfortunately this doesn't work either. Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of work and searching the Internet, I found the solution.

In the HMTL page I wrote this:

```
 <!-- Set ajax url -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            trackHistory = false;
            var ajaxUrl = 'ajaxtable.php?lid=$lid';
        </script>
<body id="page2" onload="toAjaxTableEditor('update_html','');">
```

In my receiving AJAX Table Editor software script I wrote:

```
function initiateEditor()
{
    $tableColumns['locationid'] = array('display_text' => '', 'perms' => '','data_filters' => array('filters' => array("='".$_SESSION['lid']."'")), 'default' => $_SESSION['lid']);
```

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Kind regards